# Scrapy crawler: Unable to store multiple urls into postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I have created a crawler using scrapy python.I want to store multiple urls fetched by the crawler into the postgres table.When i start the crawler the urls are fetched and table gets created into the postgres but the data is not getting stored.

**Technology used:** Scrapy,Python

**Output to be:** The urls should get stored inside the postgres table.

**Error:** I am unable to store all the urls.The crawler is not working for all the websites.

**Please Help!!!**

```js
import scrapy
import os
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database="postgres", user='postgres', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432'
)
print("connected")
conn.autocommit = True
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_crawler
(
WEBSITE VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
)

""")


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    allowed_domains=['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com//'] 
    

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            abs_url = response.urljoin(url)
            var1  = "INSERT INTO tmp_crawler(website) VALUES('" + url + "')"
         cur.execute(var1)
        conn.commit()
        yield {'title': abs_url}
```

Comment: Add some print() or breakpoint() statements to your code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Not a python guru myself, but are you sure this code is safe from SQL injection? And what about error handling? What error does the database return?

Comment: there is no error message I am getting. I am seeing that only 1 record is inserted. Others are not getting inserted.

Comment: It looks like `cur.execute` is outside the for loop, so it's only executed for the final item

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrapy` `ITEM_PIPELINES` to achieve this. See sample implementation below

```py
import scrapy
import psycopg2

class DBPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        # connect to database
        try:
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres", user = "postgres", password = "password", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
            self.conn.autocommit = True
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        except:
            spider.logger.error("Unable to connect to database") 

        # create the table
        try:
            self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_crawler (website VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL);")
        except:
            spider.logger.error("Error creating table `tmp_crawler`") 

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO tmp_crawler (website) VALUES (%s)', (item.get('title'),))
            spider.logger.info("Item inserted to database")
        except Exception as e:
            spider.logger.error(f"Error `{e}` while inserting item <{item.get('title')}")
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    allowed_domains=['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/'] 
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            DBPipeline: 500
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield {'title': response.urljoin(url)}
```